# How to pass data from child form event to parent form item?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, web-applications, silverlight-4.0

Currently I have a main form, from which I call a popup that I've created in a seperate XAML file for my spellchecker. It's called like so:

```
SpellCheckerPopupControl popupControl = new SpellCheckerPopupControl();

popupControl.SpellChecklistBox.Items.Clear();

//some code to check the word and populate the child listbox with spelling suggestions

popupControl.SpellCheckerPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

I have an event setup in the child on SelectionChanged in the listbox for it to pass the data back to the main form, currently I just want to pass the selection back to my main form so that I can take the selected word and replace the misspelled one with it. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to pass data from the child form's events back to the parent.

The XAML for the SpellCheckerPopup is just a `<PopUp>` with a `<ListBox>` inside it.

Just for testing purposes, I've tried to just take the output of what happens and paste the string into the main textbox like so: `MainPage.txtArticle.Text = s;`, but while the MainPage bit is available, none of its elements are, and as such I cannot manipulate them from the child event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a property of the window

```
var window = new popupControl.Open();
```

then on window.closed event check for `Window.txtArticle`.Text;

This should work. If not, then bind them to properties in the code behind.

[update]

Example:

```
var window = new MyTestChildWindow();
//This is just to show how to change properties in the testwindow.
window.SomeProperty = true;
window.Show();
window.Closed += (s, ea) =>
{
  if (window.DialogResult.ToBoolean())
  {
    // this is a property in the code behind.
    if (window.SelectedItem != null)
    {
      //Property = property on mainpage
      //window.SelectedItem = property in childwindow
      this.Property = window.SelectedItem;
    }
  }
};
```

this code goes in your main page.

hope this helps.

Comment: Alright, looks like the PopUp control has a .Closed event that fires when the IsOpen property gets set to false. In the child code after I select something in the listbox it gets the value of what was selected and closes the popup; but how do I pass what was selected back to my SpellCheckerPopup_Closed event handler?

Comment: Is there a way to declare a public string within the parent page and then have that variable altered in the code in the child event? After that I could use the value in the variable and update stuff on the parent page when the Closed event fires.. or is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: If you are using MVVM, you can bind both pages to that viewmodel and use the same properties (with OnPropertyChanged events). This way you wont have to use any properties or value sending between pages.
If you aren't or dont want to,
Using properties in the childwindow is like "window.<propertyname>". Not entirely sure this works for objects (textboxes etc).
And as answer to your first question in cmoment:
at the closed event: var item = window.yourdatagrid.SelectedItem;

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a property in your Program.cs file that you could pass a value to.  Then you would have access to that property application wide.  Just use:

```
Program.SomeProperty
```

Answer (score 0):

Using variables, declared somewhere else is a recipe for problem as nothing will gurantee actuality of that 'external' data.

Provided your event is a routed one, you can always query for OriginalSource and obtain information from it. If your event is not a routed one, you can create an attached event and pass your popup a OriginalSource.